# Insert 'BCH' into map

Tags: python, nested-lists

I wanted to insert 'BCH' inside a specific location in a list, but it gave me an error message.
Here is my code:

```
map = [['   ', '   ', '   ', '   '], \
       ['   ', '   ', '   ', '   '], \
       ['   ', '   ', '   ', '   '], \
       ['   ', '   ', '   ', '   ']
       ] 
building = 'BCH'
map[0][1].append(building)
```

The error message they gave was "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append' "

Comment: ```map``` is an inbuilt function. Please avoid using them as a variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strings are immutable, you can't use `.append()` on it. If you want to concatenate to the string, use an assignment.

```
map[0][1] += building
```